# Computing F1 Score using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to figure out why the F1 score is what it is in `sklearn`. I understand that it is calculated as:

```
F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
```

My code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
...
fmeasure1 = f1_score(true_output, predicted_output, average="macro")
fmeasure2 = f1_score(true_output, predicted_output, average="micro")

precision = precision_score(true_output, predicted_output, average="macro")
recall = recall_score(true_output, predicted_output, average="macro")

print 2*(precision*recall)/(precision + recall), fmeasure1, fmeasure2
```

The values I get for my data are:

```
0.785744255639 0.769527615775 0.984532095901
```

I don't understand why these three values are different from one another. I've tried reading the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html), but I'm still quite lost.

My dataset is mutli-class and, by nature, highly imbalanced. Which of the values here is the "correct" value, and by extension, which among the parameters for average (i.e. None, micro, macro, weight) should I use?

Thanks, and any insight would be highly valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the return value:

```
Returns:    
f1_score : float or array of float, shape = [n_unique_labels]
F1 score of the positive class in binary classification or weighted average of the F1 scores of each class for the multiclass task.
```

Each value is a F1 score for that particular class, so each class can be predicted with a different score.

Regarding what is the best score.

```
best value at 1 and worst score at 0.[ \[From documentation\]][1]
```

On a side note if you're dealing with highly imbalanced data sets you should consider looking into sampling methods, or simply sub-sample from your existing data if it allows.

If you want an average of predictions `average='weighted'`:

```
sklearn.metrics.f1_score(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, pos_label=1, average='weighted')
```

Comment: I don't understand. Each F1 score is for a particular class?

Comment: In the sixth line of the documentation : In the multi-class and multi-label case, this is the weighted average of the F1 score of each class.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your input. My question still remains, however: why are these values different from the value returned by: 2*(precision*recall)/(precision + recall)?

Comment: From the documentation : Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average, weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall., therefore the value returned is bound to be different. consider accepting if this answered your question

Comment: Alright, I understand now. The first value in my output takes the f-measure of the average precision and recall, whereas sklearn returns  the average f-measure of the precision and recall /per class/. Thank you.