# TypeError: f1_score() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a SGDClassifier, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: f1_score() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

This is my code:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
 ('clf', SGDClassifier())
])

parameters = {
    'clf__loss': ('log', 'hinge'),
    'clf__penalty': ['l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet'],
    'clf__alpha': [0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001]
}

score_func = make_scorer(metrics.f1_score(average='weighted'))

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3,
verbose=1, scoring=score_func)



grid_search.fit(X, Y)
```

How can I fix?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/41278032/5250746 might help

Comment: @idjaw metrics is a submodule in sklearn, f1_score is a utility function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the scoring function as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score


f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score,average='weighted')

grid_search =GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3,verbose=1, scoring=f1_scorer)
```

This works fine and does what you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass it like this:

```
make_scorer(metrics.f1_score, average='weighted')
```

You should pass the function name, and any associated keyword arguments separately.

[Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) for reference.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki You're supposed to pass the function name _without calling it_. With their code, OP is actually calling it (and incorrectly) raising the error.